SwiftUI: Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable
Currently learning Swift (in Xcode specifically), and this seemingly very simple operation isn't working. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong (simplified code):
var taps: Int = 0

var body: some View {
    Button(action: { taps += 1 }) { /* ... */ } // Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'self' is immutable
}

I've tried a few variations of this, including taps = taps + 1, which didn't work for the same reason. My understanding is that in Swift, var is mutable, so what's wrong here?

SwiftUI views get recreated often when screen updates. Since taps represent state, you need to use @State property wrapper in a SwiftUI view to be able to preserve it (also, it's recommended to keep state vars private): @State private var taps: Int = 0.

That was it, thanks! If you wanna submit that as an answer for posterity I can accept it.
